Заполнение шаблона в Microsoft Word с артефактами
я формирую отчет в из Delphi (вставляю в существующий шаблон Microsoft Word данные из базы (т.е. заменяю параметры в шаблоне на значения из базы)), вот кусок кода
var
  TypeDos_Templs: variant;


...  TypeDos_Templs.Selection.Find.Forward := True;
TypeDos_Templs.Selection.Find.Wrap := wdFindContinue;
TypeDos_Templs.Selection.Find.Format := true;

TypeDos_Templs.Selection := TEXT_STYLE(TypeDos_Templs.Selection, AUnderLine, ABold, AItalic);

TypeDos_Templs.Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Color := AColor;....

и функция которая задаёт стиль текста
function TEXT_STYLE(ASource: Variant;
                    AUnderLine, ABold, AItalic: integer): Variant;

begin
  if AUnderLine = 1 then
    ASource.Find.Replacement.Font.Underline := true
  else ASource.Find.Replacement.Font.Underline := false;

  if ABold = 1 then
      ASource.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold := true
  else ASource.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold := false;

  if AItalic = 1 then
    ASource.Find.Replacement.Font.Italic := true
  else ASource.Find.Replacement.Font.Italic := false;
  Result := ASource;
end;

раньше, когда функции "TEXT_STYLE" не было, а ее код был вместо ее вызова, и отчёт формировался отлично.
Но когда я сделал эту функцию "TEXT_STYLE", отчёт тоже формируется, НО в нем стали появляться дополнительные символы (например символ "перевода каретки на другую строку"), количеством равным числу подставляемых значений из базы.
В чем может быть причина?
Вот интересно, а если обращаться к функции просто:
TEXT_STYLE(TypeDos_Templs.Selection, AUnderLine, ABold, AItalic);

То всё работает отлично

Т.к. Selection - это Ole объект, то присвоение ему значения вызывает некоторое количество скрытых от программиста действий, которые могут приводить к такому эффекту. В чём смысл использования именно функции?

Смысл прост: код (я его еще немножко расширю) нужно использовать в нескольких местах. Я уже переделал ее в процедуру...
Спс за ответ

Сделайте TEXT_STYLE процедурой с var-параметром
